# Need help understanding smart contract method call of tzBTC

Tags: operation, json

I need to be able to reconstruct history of transactions in tzBTC contract:

https://better-call.dev/mainnet/KT1PWx2mnDueood7fEmfbBDKx1D9BAnnXitn/operations

If we filter operations by mint, we get two operations, one of which is:

https://better-call.dev/mainnet/opg/onpWkaPJKm5emvAEvVUncBbaeyBYfDZ7J4DsUwHmTRb2V16SXUg/contents

If we look at JSON representation of that transaction, we see that real call of tzBTC smart contract happens in internal operation:

```
"internal_operation_results" : [
    {
        "kind" : "transaction",
        "source" : "KT1FcmdSroia1ys1WM6mL2rzB1haLxyy3MH9",
        "nonce" : 0,
        "amount" : "0",
        "destination" : "KT1PWx2mnDueood7fEmfbBDKx1D9BAnnXitn",
        "parameters" : {
            "entrypoint" : "safeEntrypoints",
            "value" : {
                "prim" : "Right",
                "args" : [
                    {
                        "prim" : "Left",
                        "args" : [
                            {
                                "prim" : "Left",
                                "args" : [
                                    {
                                        "prim" : "Left",
                                        "args" : [
                                            {
                                                "prim" : "Pair",
                                                "args" : [
                                                    {
                                                        "bytes" : "000070cf0ac51caaf043ed04fdc8bef779e17c84a2dd"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "int" : "35693999960"
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
```

I can decode address from Micheline format, no question there. My real problem is how better-call.dev knows this is call of mint operation if JSON representation of transaction says safeEntrypoints? There are two more operations with safeEntrypoints, one is another mint and other is op1UEZ7ZrUoWrAG8juS9FvmrmJvzK8N1vFSF8GGCv8WciMVHDrw - acceptOwnership. The only difference in JSON part between mint and acceptOwnership is set of parameters, I have not seen anything which would tell mint from acceptOwnership. Here is the JSON for op1UEZ7ZrUoWrAG8juS9FvmrmJvzK8N1vFSF8GGCv8WciMVHDrw acceptOwnership operation:

```
"internal_operation_results" : [
    {
        "kind" : "transaction",
        "source" : "KT1QeoDkCAdJSSnm7zWz6Nv7W82qaoUz7kC9",
        "nonce" : 0,
        "amount" : "0",
        "destination" : "KT1PWx2mnDueood7fEmfbBDKx1D9BAnnXitn",
        "parameters" : {
            "entrypoint" : "safeEntrypoints",
            "value" : {
                "prim" : "Right",
                "args" : [
                    {
                        "prim" : "Right",
                        "args" : [
                            {
                                "prim" : "Right",
                                "args" : [
                                    {
                                        "prim" : "Right",
                                        "args" : [
                                            {
                                                "prim" : "Right",
                                                "args" : [
                                                    {
                                                        "prim" : "Unit"
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
```

But somehow better-call.dev is intelligent enough to understand the real method being called are mint and acceptOwnership, instead of safeEntrypoints. How does it do this? I tried to look through tzBTC sources - https://github.com/tz-wrapped/tezos-btc/ however learning curve to start understanding smart contracts in Tezos is far to steep for my purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of entrypoints is very lightweight in Michelson, and under the hood it's still a value of a single type that is actually passed to the script. Hence the various ways to do the same thing, e.g:

```
KT1VG2WtYdSWz5E7chTeAdDPZNy2MpP8pTfL            (Left (Left ($Arg)))
KT1VG2WtYdSWz5E7chTeAdDPZNy2MpP8pTfL%default    (Left (Left ($Arg)))
KT1VG2WtYdSWz5E7chTeAdDPZNy2MpP8pTfL%fund       (Left ($Arg))
KT1VG2WtYdSWz5E7chTeAdDPZNy2MpP8pTfL%initiate   ($Arg)
```

Same story with the tzBTC contract: you can call the same method using `default`, `safeEntrypoints`, or `mint` entrypoint, but the values will be different.
BCD looks at the parameter type of the contract and realizes that one can get from `safeEntrypoints` to `mint` if omit the wrapping Lefts/Rights.

Further reading:
[1] [Michelson entrypoints](https://tezos.gitlab.io/alpha/michelson.html?highlight=entrypoint#entrypoints)
[2] [Parameter normalization](https://baking-bad.org/blog/2020/08/28/off-chain-events-and-tezos-tokens-indexing/#normalizing-parameters)